# How to use mail_to tag in rails 4 using haml?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, haml, mailto

I want to use mailto with my rails 4 in haml, that too with rails i8n. I tried doing it this way

```
%a{href: Content.email, mailto: true, target: '_blank'}
= t :footer_email_us
```

But, in this way when I click on the link, I get the wrong email id attached in the to field.

Comment: try this: = mail_to "#{Content.email}", "#{Content.email}", target: '_blank'

Comment: Why two times of Content.email, my text is coming from internationalization,

Comment: one time for link and one time for display 
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/mail_to

Comment: thank you @Sunny but my displayed text is coming from rails i8n, do you have any idea how can I give that using above text.

Comment: what is the text coming from rails i18n ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the correct way to do it, using the internationalization text.

```
= mail_to Content.email, t('footer_email_us')
```